# Can I add a whole Bootstrap only project to a new Angular one?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I've got a ready Bootstrap project (with good UI&UX) but I'm not sure if I can import it straightaway in my Angular one. I saw some tips to add bootstrap on the internet but there wasn't a guide how to import a whole ready one.

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can add. If the project is not using BS4 yet, then you have to install it, and can use the bs4 classes as you would use outside of an Angular app.